# Overflow menu icon not visible...

Tags: android

### I am adding the toolbar to linear layout     I have created a toolbar without using xml.Everything is working fine but i am not able to add overflow menu .Overflow icon is not showing

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_lnrLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.smartify.customizetoolbardemo.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnrlayout_toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">
  </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your java to see what you are doing there.

Answer (score 0):

Add a menu to your toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        />
</menu>
```

inflate you menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

You will get icon of overflow menu then.

Comment: I have tried this....but not working....When i am specifying toolbar in xml,it is showing icon ....but not when added programmatically

Comment: Have you tried this "toolbar.setOverflowIcon(some image here);" This may solve the issue of icon display.

Comment: Use this to add menu. "toolbar.setMenu(parameters here);"

Comment: can you provide any example for using toolbar.setMenu()??

Answer (score 0):

Add one button or any view in your`lnrlayout_toolbar`

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
showPopupMenu(btn);
```

and call below method for showing overlay menu

```
public void showPopupMenu(View v){
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.sub_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

**is sub_menu** is your menu file that you want to show..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

***XML code for menu items*** 
create menu resource in res>>menu>>menu_optipn.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:title="item1"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:title="item2"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    />
```

MainActivity.Java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_option, menu);
    return true;
}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item 1 is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item 2 is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working when i am adding Toolbar in xml , but not when added programmatically